# Single page Web App (Phonegap) - cordova.js failing

Tags: android, cordova, browser

Im trying to setup a simple **single page web app for Android**, using phonegap, but i always have an error on console saying: `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   /C:/path/to/project/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js:925"`

**Cordova version:** 3.5.0 - Android

**Line 925:** `var messages = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(service, action, callbackId, argsJson);`

im trying to run this web app in my desktop brownser (chrome), for testing.

I tried different resources for this cordova.js file, but without success. Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: If you are using phonegap build {Bd} then, don't include cordova.js in your assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use cordova.js in your browser. You will need some kind of emulatator. Like ripple emulator.

[Ripple emulator](http://emulate.phonegap.com/)

Or test on android emulator or in your device etc.

Comment: before i was testing simple apps without problems on my desktop browser.

Comment: So far I know, device ready won't be fired. cordova.js file won't be found by the desktop browsers normally. Normal browser will try to find the cordova.js file inside your `www` folder. You can check the error with 'Inspect element features' from browsers in console section.

Comment: runing the emulator gives me the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Object true has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:925

Comment: i have created a new project, step by step once again, and tested on device. Working now on device, but not on browser. Like AtanuCSE answered.